# How to determine the no of multiplication operations in convolution operation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, computer-vision, convolution

Let's say We have an input of size 28×28×192. We apply 32,  5×5 convolution filters with padding "same". How many multiplication operations will be there in total?
I know there will be 28*28*32 * 5*5*192 multiplications, But I cannot understand how. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: If your convolution kernel is 5x5, then your multiplication operations will be 25, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no dilation, stride equal to $1$ and padding equal to `same`, the output and input size are the same. For each output pixel, we have a complete element-wise multiplication between the filter and the input, i.e. $5\times 5$ multiplications. Since there are $32$ filters, for each output pixel (with channels accounted), we have $32\times 5\times 5$ multiplications. Because the output size is $28\times28\times192$, the total number of multiplications equates to $28\times28\times192\times5\times5\times32=120422400$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but gunes made some mistakes that I have to point out. For each output pixel, we actually have 5 x 5 x 192 multiplications. The output size is 28 x 28 x 32 (not 28 x 28 x 192). The thing you should keep in mind is that the number of kernels equals the number of output channels. Hence, the total number of multiplications is (28 x 28 x 32) x (5 x 5 x 192).

Answer (score 0):

The input shape = (28 * 28 *192)
The output shape = (28 *28 *32) as 32 filters were used
the kernel shape in each filter will be = (5 *5)(input shape dimension(depth)) = (5 *5 *192)(imagine 28 *28 as image and the 192 such images stacked to perform convolution our kernel should match the depth of the input)

in each convolution operation or dot product operation we get one output and total such output results in our output shape = (28 *28 *32)

no.of dot products = (28*28*32) = output shape
no.of multiplications = no.of dot products * (kernel shape) = (28*28*32).(5*5*192)
no.of additions = no.of multiplications - 1